# Вывод предметов Steam Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, steam

Добрый день.
Не могли бы вы подсказать как реализовать вывод предметов Steam в Wordpress? Подключен плагин аутентификации Steam (API).

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь с этим ответом, разобраться не тяжело, главное знать айди пользователя, и потом можно будет выводить уже все предметы его.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393099/getting-someones-steam-inventory